# Can not override value with helm template/lint using --set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm Chart that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
name: my-app
version: 1.0-123.4b3k32
```

I am trying to use helm template (or lint, it doesn't matter, they both throw the same error). With helm2 this wasn't a problem, but with helm3, it is complaining that

```
Error: validation: chart.metadata.version "1.0-304.0770996" is invalid
```

Now when executing helm template, I want to override this value using

```
helm template --set chart.metadata.version='0.0.0'
```

but I keep getting the same error, what am I doing wrong here?

Changing it in the Chart itself is not an option. I tested by changing it manually to 0.0.0 to see if it works and it does. Setting it to 0.0.0 during templating would be fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chart.yaml `version:` field](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#charts-and-versioning) is specified to be a [semantic version](https://semver.org); quoting the Helm documentation, "non-SemVer names are explicitly disallowed by the system."  SerVer's rule 2 is:

> A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are non-negative integers....

So changing the chart version to `1.0.0-456.a1b2c3d` might resolve this problem.  (SerVer rule 9 allows the `-456...` suffix to indicate a pre-release version but all of its examples have three-part versions before the hyphen.)

There is no way to override these `Chart.yaml` values with [`helm install`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) or related commands.  In particular `helm install --set` provides overrides to the `values.yaml` file, what template code sees as `.Values`.